# ExtJs(4.2.0) Editable Grid with xtype : button column

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-grid

Below is an executable piece of code having a button in the editor of the grid. I need the button to be present in the editor, however i do not need any value of/from the button to be updated. The update functionality of the editor doesn't seem to be working anymore. Any idea what i could be missing?

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'EmployeeData',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        {"name":"aaa", "email":"aaa@emp.com", "phone":"987654321"},
        {"name":"bbb", "email":"bbb@emp.com", "phone":"987654321"},
        {"name":"ccc", "email":"ccc@emp.com", "phone":"987654321"},
        {"name":"ddd", "email":"ddd@emp.com", "phone":"987654321"}
    ]});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Employee',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('EmployeeData'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'},
        {header: 'button', dataIndex:'',editor:{xtype:'button',editable: false}}
    ],
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1,
            pluginId: 'rowEditing'
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: It loos like that code should produce a grid with 4 rows and 4 columns.  What were you expecting?

Comment: If you happened to read the description it says that since there is a column of xtype button the editor doesnt work.

Comment: You could run this in fiddle. The editor doesnt work due the xtype button column.

Comment: There may be another way to do what you want this button to do... Could you explain what would a button click do? You may use a customized [RowEditingButtons](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/RowEditorButtons.html#Ext-grid-RowEditorButtons) plugin to add your custom button...

Comment: So on button click i have a popup with a set of numbers in another grid, and on click of any of those number some of the columns in the open editor should change.

Comment: @MichelFRANKE Could you please give me an example of how to use the  RowEditingButtons plugin?

Comment: [This example](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?285311-Custom-RowEditing-buttons-in-Ext-5) could help you

Answer (score 0):

The editor uses `getValue()` function on each `x-field`, the button control does not have `getValue()` function and hence it is throwing exception and fails to update the record.

Maybe you can use [`ActionColumn`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action) if it can serve your purpose. You can attach handler function the same way you do with button.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to this, but I just ran into the same issue.

You can add a `getValue` method to allow the update action to function correctly.

```
editor: {
    xtype: 'button',
    getValue: function() {
        return true;
    }
}
```